# elasticsearch must_not returning wrong values

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong with my Elastic query. I'm trying to filter out all the docs that have "Software Engineer" as their title. my Query:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [{
            "term": {
              "title.keyword": "Software Engineer"
            }
          }]
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

in my mapping...

```
"title": {"type": "text"}
```

Then my results:

```
hits:[
{title: "Software Engineer"},
{title: "Engineer"},
{title: "Software Engineer"},
{title: "Software and Data Quality Manager"},
...
]
```

I would like to not get Software Engineer in my search results here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) if you want to map the `title` field as `text` and `keyword` type. Modify your index mapping to

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": { 
            "type":  "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "title": "Software and Data Quality Manager"
}
{
  "title": "Software Engineer"
}
{
  "title": "Engineer"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "term": {
          "title.keyword": "Software Engineer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66064654",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Engineer"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66064654",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Software and Data Quality Manager"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I've made the change in my mapping, and I'm still getting the same results. I imagine this is because there is some propagation happening under the hood where my index is being eventually updated to have this field (some 60k docs in it)

Does that sound reasonable? Your results seem indisputable, so i'm trying to figure out where i'm still going wrong.

Comment: @Ben but it looks like you already have `title.keyword` field, as shown in the query posted in your question.

Comment: Apparently, it appears to be the case that you have text mappings defined on the field over which you are doing search. So it would be better to confirm that first.

Answer (score 1):

You query is correct and keyword by default is no operation tokenizer, so please check to be sure you are not using any type of normalizer for your keywrod type in index and search time that causing change to your text. If you use default keyword also be aware that your search will be treated case sensitive except that you use normalizer during searech and index.